# Call function after delay on page load using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a function in Angular 2.5 seconds after a page loads to see if a form field has been autofilled.  The function is being called but for some reason is only called if I navigate away from the field, change the tab, minimize the browser, etc.  How can I accomplish this without requiring the user to do any of these actions (i.e. it is called 2.5 seconds after page load no matter what).  I have two different implementations I have tried below but they behave the same way.

Method 1:

```
var timer=false;
$scope.$watch('email', function(){
    if(timer){
         $timeout.cancel(timer)
}
    timer= $timeout(function(){
        $scope.emailChanged();
    }, 250)
});
```

Method 2:

```
<div class="form-managed" ng-init="load()"></div>

$scope.load = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
            $scope.emailChanged();
    }, 2500);
 };
```

Update:

From comments I changed the code to use $timeout instead of my other implementations.  I also verified that the function is being called in any of the implementations however the value of the field still shows as null when I try to extract it.  Current code below.

```
$timeout(() => {
    debugger;
    var thisEmail = document.getElementById("buyerEmail");
    $scope.emailChanged();
}, 5000);
```

Input field:

`<input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="buyerEmail" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="email" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-change="emailChanged($event)" required />`

Comment: put a simple console.log into the function and you will see, that it is called

Comment: Timeout in first is only 250ms. And why is it inside watch email?

Comment: You're right webdeb it does appear that it is being called but stepping through the function the value that is entered in the form is not being recorded.  Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Arg0n, typo.  It is 2500 in code like the second method shows

Comment: This is not what `ng-nit` is for. Call function in controller

Comment: @thurmc Why is this even needed? From your description, it seems like email is being filled in from code and not updated as expected. The 2.5 second delay is not going to be a good solution for a production environment. Instead, nest your assignment inside a `$timeout` call.

Comment: @Arg0n The OP said it was a typo. Why are you being rude?

Comment: @CobusKruger he changed his comment. He was the one being rude. It was like: '@Arg0n 2500 = 2500ms = 2.5s ...' and a link to w3schools i believe xD.

Comment: @Arg0n Okay, I didn't see that.

Comment: My comment isn't edited

Comment: @CobusKruger I changed it to that but I'm still having a problem grabbing the value from the field (it still shows as null).  I added an id field "buyerEmail".  Below are the function and tag, with terrible formatting sorry :(

 $timeout(() => {
  debugger;
  var thisEmail = document.getElementById("buyerEmail").nodeValue;
  $scope.emailChanged();
 }, 5000);

<input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="buyerEmail" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="email" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-change="emailChanged($event)" required />

Comment: @thurmc please add this to the question itself. Aside from better formatting, readers of the question often miss extra information in the comments.

Comment: Oh good call.  One sec I'll add it

Comment: @thurmc I think you misunderstood my comment. I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference how long the delay is that you add. If you populated the value of your email input from code, Angular doesn't see the change. This is why you only see the change reflected once you resize or make some other change that forces Angular to process the page.

While you didn't show it, I assume you have some code somewhere to assign the email value. Something like this, perhaps:

```
$("txtEmail").val(myEmailVariable);
```

Change it to this:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $("txtEmail").val(myEmailVariable);
});
```

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for your help :)